# Хранение часового пояса юзера

Tags: php, javascript, дата

Получаю часовой пояс юзера с помощью JS функцией getTimezoneOffset().Где будет правильнее ее хранить в дальнейшем чтобы работать,так как будет несколько функций по работе со временем,и надо будет передать в них часовой пояс юзера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если пользователям соответствуют записи в таблице базы данных, например, users, лучше в ней в виде целого числа (со знаком, так как смещение положительное и отрицательное от UTC). Конечно, есть дробные часовые пояса в районе Океании, но их можно игнорировать. Большая проблема заключается в зимнем/летнем времени. Да, в РФ оно отменено, однако, в мире оно еще много где есть, поэтому помимо поля под часовой пояс, хорошо бы предусмотреть флажок: учитывать или не учитывать зимнее время.

Если пользователи не регистрируются - все тоже самое, но в сессии пользователя ($_SESSION).

Comment: Плюс еще момент дата регистрация пользователя,на данный момент это время сервера,или надо будет учитывать его время? Просто с датой не очень часто приходилось работать,поэтому много ньюансов!

Comment: Используйте функцию gmdate(), она вернет UTC-время.

Comment: И потом прибавлять к ней часовой пояс юзера?

Comment: Ага. Фактически часовой пояс нужно будет добавлять к любой выводимой дате, почему и удобно хранить в utc - манипуляций меньше.

Comment: Спасибо большое,очень помогли!