# Как сделать отправку сообщений учитывая часовой пояс?

Tags: php, timezone

Нужно учитывать часовой пояс для отправки сообщений пользователю crm щас только пришел к выводу что надо это делать. Допустим у пользователя будет возможность задать часовой пояс поле "timezone".

щас скрипт примерно такой:

```
    // Варианты напоминания
    $timeto  = array(
        array("timeto" => "day_1","sec" => "86400",),
        array("timeto" => "houre_1","sec" => "3600"),
        array("timeto" => "min_30","sec" => "1800"),
        array("timeto" => "min_15","sec" => "900"),
        array("timeto" => "min_10","sec" => "600"),

    );
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($timeto); $i++) {



    $time_to = $timeto[$i]['timeto'];
    $time_to_sec = $timeto[$i]['sec'];

    $rem_remember = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE $time_to = '1' and status = '0'");

        while($row_remember = mysql_fetch_array($rem_remember)){    

        $now_date = mktime();

        $start_datetime = strtotime("$row_remember[start_date] $row_remember[start_time]");
        $end_datetime = strtotime("$row_remember[end_date] $row_remember[end_time]");

        $date_rememder = $start_datetime-$time_to_sec;

            $limit_date_rememder = 60+$date_rememder; // расчет времени вс секундах + 1 минута 

                if ($now_date >= $date_rememder and $now_date <= $limit_date_rememder) {


// отправляем письмо 

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно хранить дату и время в базе данных в формате UTC и просто прибавлять или вычитать количество часов, соответствующих часовому поясу пользователя

```
SELECT
  id,
  timeto - INTERVAL timezone HOUR,
  start_date - INTERVAL timezone HOUR,
  end_date - INTERVAL timezone HOUR
FROM
  tasks
WHERE
  $time_to = '1' and status = '0'"
```

Comment: ну я щас уже не переделаю огромную базу и дата там храниться в виде 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: В каком часовом поясе хранится дата и время? Можно сделать поправку на учет этого часового пояса.

Comment: вообще московское время

Comment: Сместите значение timezone на 3 часа, так чтобы оно учитывало, что отсчет идет не от 0 часовой зоны UTC, а от московской -3, т.е. если у вас пользователь выбирает московское время, у него timezone  = 0, а если UTC: +3

Comment: Плюс одного поля timezone вам может оказаться мало, так как в некоторых странах поддерживается зимнее/летнее время http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503294

Comment: да мне пока россия и украина максимум не хочется перепиливать пол системы

Comment: ну вот допустим если часовой пояс +1 час от московского времени, то как мне быть? как все это в системе замутить с текущим кодом.

Comment: Так как вы решили использовать timezone - то просто сохраните для пользователя в timezone значение 1, которое затем используйте в вычислениях текущей даты во всех SQL-запросах. Скорее всего, вы будете хранить это поле где-то в таблице users, скорее всего вам придется извлекать его и хранить в сессии, при формировании SQL-запроса можно подставлять в конструкцию INTERVAL ... HOUR часовой пояс из сессии пользователя. Можно даже пойти дальше и определять его JavaScript http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502942

Comment: я понял! В моем конкретном примере как мне например применить?